# M2: How can I override Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current?

Tags: magento2, plugin

I used Plugin for this, But my plugin is not working.
Below is my code.
di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current">
    <plugin name="Current" type="CP\Coreoverride\Plugin\Current" />
</type>
```

Current.php

```
<?php
namespace CP\Coreoverride\Plugin;

class Current{

  protected function _toHtml()
  {
    echo "fdsfds"; die;
  }

}
```

Anyone can look into please.

Answer (score 1):

You can't plugin a protected method

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

**Limitations**
Plugins can not be used on following:

- Final methods
- Final classes
- Non-public methods
- Class methods (such as
  static methods)
- __construct Virtual types
- Objects that are instantiated before Magento\Framework\Interception is bootstrapped

so your best bet is to either plug a first public method in inheritance chain

```
grep '>_toHtml(' vendor/magento/framework/View -rsn 
vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:659: $html = $this->_toHtml();
```

and that is `Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock` `toHtml` method

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Can you please suggest. How can I achieve this ? I want override protected function _toHtml().

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use the plugin you need to need to add `After`, `Before` or `Around` before the function. Please check the following link for more detail.

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: You can't plugin a protected method